# Umbraco uCommerce Secure Trading - need to use OrderNumber instead of OrderGuid

Tags: payment, umbraco-ucommerce, secure-trading

I am trying to use umbraco with uCommerce.

I have implemented SecureTrading as Payment provider in uCommerce. Now I need a solution to use OrderNumber in place of OdrderGuid to be used to identify the PurchaseOrder.

Currently OrderGuid is being sento to SecureTrading & this is being displayed in SecureTrading Transactions section. And due to this identifying the order is really hard.

We have appropriate value in OrderNumber field of PurchaseOrder table & we want to Display that value in SecureTrading's Transaction section.

Any way to achieve this?

If I try to write my own payment provider code, it'll be very huge task, also we have set the SecureTrading environment accordingly to uCommerce default preference.

Immediate help is required.

**For more Detail** 
I have developed a DLL for my own customization as menthioned in http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.3/payment-providers/integrating-a-payment-gateway.html But, that also is not working. the custom Payment Provider added in code(DLL) is not visible in backoffice to change the Payment Provider. There are all old entries for providers.

Even nothing shows up in cms Admin section for uCommerce Settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a derrived version of the PageBuilder which will send the parameters to SecureTrading.

There's a protected virtual method you can override called "GetParameters".

It returns a dictionary that holds everything that will be send to SecureTrading.

You can set the "orderreference" in the dictionary to OrderNumber. This originally holds the orderguid.

Don't forget to register your page builder in the IoC container.

http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.5/extending-ucommerce/register-a-component.html

You need to override the component by reusing the ID that the page builder has, which is: "SecureTradingPageBuilder". When overriding the page builder you don't have to change anything in the back office.

This should fix your problem :)